# How to change background image of EditText by SharedPreference choice?

Tags: android, image, android-edittext

I have been trying without success to change the background image of an EditText using a preference choice. I don't know why it isn't working. here is my code:

```
preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefBorder", 0);
String value = preferences.getString("Solid", null);

if (value.equals("Solid")) {
    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
    // the key does not exist
} else {
    // handle the value
    editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderpkmnblue);
}
```

Here are my preference values for the borders:

```
<string-array name="Border">
    <item name="Solid">Solid</item>
    <item name="PokemonBlue">Pokemon Blue</item>

</string-array>
<string-array name="borderValues">
    <item name="Solid">drawable/border.png</item>
    <item name="PokemonBlue">drawable/borderpkmnblue.png</item>

</string-array>
```

Comment: Solid is your preference key, what is your preference value? Is it Solid too?

Comment: Added array list for borders

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `setBackgroundDrawable()` method instead

```
editText.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.border);
```

Comment: And it doesn't work anyway.  It says cannot be applied

Comment: What do you actually store inside of your SharedPreferences file? Your key is "Solid" but what is it's value?

Comment: You mean my settings xml file?

Comment: Oh, the value is         drawable/border.png

Comment: No, you must have stored something inside of your SharedPreferences file, right? With a method like editor.putString("Solid", "some value"); ? And you get that value using preferences.getString("Solid", null);..

Comment: No...I really need help with this and i am kind of confused. I'm a sort of beginner so I apologize for my confusion

Comment: If you haven't actually stored anything inside of your SharedPreferences, then why are you even trying to get the value from it? Do you actually know what a SharedPreference is? Anyway, what is it exactly that you want to do?

Comment: I want to have a selection between two borders and have the user choose one in Preferences, and I want the user's selected border to be the background image of my EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the BackgroundResource function:

```
editText.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.edit_text);
```

And the drawable should be a 9 patch file.